# CoordinatorLayout leaves empty bottom space

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I'm developing and Android App using Xamarin. I'm using the ViewPager with TabLayout to make tab navigation, but my ViewPager, even with height="match_parent" does not fill the whole screen.
I believe it's some misconfiguration on CoordinatorLayout, but I can't find a way to fix it.

My layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/background_aulas"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/aulas_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="75px"
            local:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/aulas_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="@id/appbarlayout" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is a screenshot of my screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN9hE.jpg

Comment: "the blue bar" is coming from where?

Comment: add android:fitsSystemWindows= true in CoordinatorLayout!

Comment: why your viewpager have match parent for width and height? and also weight?

Comment: @Aashavi The blue background is the CoordinatorLayout background.

Comment: @Coeus I want my ViewPager to occupy the whole area of the CoordinatorLayout, so I set width and height as match_parent. Am I wrong? The weight attribute was just another try to make it happen.

Comment: Yep, If your want to work with weight you should set your width or height with "0dp", depends of what you want to do. For example I usually set my height of some linear layouts with "0dp" and weight with 1 and the other with weight 2. Then they adjust proportionally to the screen

Comment: @Coeus Got it! I'll try it!

Comment: But the ImageView and the TabLayout also occupy part of the CoordinatorLayout, so surely you need the ViewPager to just fill the remaining space?

Comment: @QuantumTiger Yes. I need it to fill the remaining space. It would be interesting if the CoordinatorLayout could overlap just a little space of the ImageView. The designer suggested the layout this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
  <ImageView
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" />
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:id="@+id/appbarlayout">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/aulas_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="75px"
        local:tabMode="scrollable" />
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/aulas_viewpager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#FF0000"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="@id/appbarlayout" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to CoordinatorLayout was the answer =D