# Stop fragments going over ActionBar in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

As you can see in the image below, the 'Updates fragment' TextView is being written above the ActionBar. I am trying to make it so that this text sits below the TabBar, where you'd expect it.

[image]

The main activity layout is a CoordinatorLayout, containing the typical AppBarLayout, and then a ViewPager.

The ViewPager is filling the whole screen (which I understand it has to), but how can I change my layout so that the fragment sits under the tabs and fills the remaining part of the screen from there?

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_updates.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UpdatesFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Updates fragment" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.joel.myapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Stack"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: this is happening because you have `AppBarOverlay` theme activated on `AppBarLayout` I think? can you show the code for that theme?

Comment: @Bhargav It's just a default Android theme I selected, which is the most common theme? I'll select that to see if it fixes it

Comment: @Bhargav Removing the theme doesn't fix the problem, the TextView still remains in the upper left corner

Comment: just post your styles.xml here plus your manifest I want to see what theme you have applied to your app and this particular activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you correctly identified part of the problem in your comments - that `CoordinatorLayout` inherits from `FrameLayout`, and as such your current layout file simply tells the `ViewPager` to fill the entire screen and go on top of other content (as seen in your photo).

**Edit:** I've realised since posting this advice below, in quotes, isn't relevant to your question as it stands. It is only important if you want to create collapsing toolbar behaviour.

> To resolve it, and keep using `CoordinatorLayout`, you would need to
>   assign a behaviour to your content, which is only possible on a layout
>   with nested scrolling (`RecyclerView` and `NestedScrollView`).
>
> You could therefore try wrapping the layout file for each of your
>   Fragments inside the `ViewPager` inside a `NestedScrollView`.

Additionally, you can try adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your `ViewPager`.

Comment: As this answer and the other answer were both submitted at almost the same time I have selected this one as best as it provides further explanation.

Comment: Would a different layout (eg RelativeLayout) be more appropriate here? I just have 3 tabs, that look like the one in the screenshot.

Comment: @jksidd3 If you aren't going to take advantage of any co-ordinator layout behaviour, then possibly, although as you have now done most of the work I would probably stick with it. This because it provides additional flexibility and animations without any additional work on your part.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are usigng CoOrdinatorLayout:-

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you it works! Could you please explain why adding that layout_behaviour fixed the problem so I know for future reference?

Comment: So CoordinatorLayout is extended FrameLayout - which means it is drawing stuff on top of each other. But it have this layout_behaviour where you can do whole lot of scrolling stuff, (it also tells the coordinator to draw it one below another): https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score -1):

Try adding layout_below AppBarLayout to ViewPager:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="--some id of AppBarLayout--" />
```

Comment: This made no difference unfortunately

Comment: change the layout_height of ViewPager to android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: ok, i got it wrong. Coordinator Layout is Frame Layout which means it will draw on top of another. Try adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to ViewPager (you can revert other changes)

Comment: Still the same annoyingly, would a different Layout be better than Coordinator Layout?

Comment: This is funny now. OK, try this last thing: add this to ViewPager app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: Please see the selected answer for the correct solution